# Decrypting a CipherInputStream results in an empty stream

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, jce

I seem to be have an issue with JCE. I create an `CipherInputStream` using an encrypting JCE cipher which I then use to create another `CipherInputStream` using a different decrypting JCE cipher.

When I try to read then second stream all I get is empty data. I found no documentation forbidding the above behavior. Does anyone know what the problem is?

This is the code which I am running, at the end plainText is empty (the same issue persists regardless of what `SecurityProvider` I use).

```
InputStream payload = new ByteArrayInputStream(payloadArray);
Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", "SunJCE");
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IV);
InputStream encryptStream = new CipherInputStream(payload, encryptCipher);

Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES", "SunJCE");
decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IV);
InputStream decryptStream = new CipherInputStream(encryptStream, decryptCipher);

byte[] plainText = IOUtisl.toByteArray(decryptStream);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you left out the parts for the key and the IV parameter find a small snippet, based on your provided code.

```
// add proper exception handling, left out only for the example
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String transformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    String provider = "SunJCE";
    String algorithm = "AES";
    byte[] payloadArray = "secret text".getBytes();

    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm, provider);
    keyGen.init(128);
    Key key = keyGen.generateKey();

    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
    SecureRandom prng = new SecureRandom();
    prng.nextBytes(ivBytes);
    IvParameterSpec IV = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

    Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation, provider);
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IV);

    InputStream payload = new ByteArrayInputStream(payloadArray);
    InputStream encryptStream = new CipherInputStream(payload, encryptCipher);

    Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation, provider);
    decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IV);
    InputStream decryptStream = new CipherInputStream(encryptStream, decryptCipher);

    for (int i = decryptStream.read(); i >= 0; i = decryptStream.read()) {
        System.out.print((char) i);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
secret text
```